# How to use dotnet restore on Visual Studio Team Services Hosted Build Agent with VSTS Nuget feed

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I have a .Net Core 1.0 class library that uses a Nuget package that is hosted in a Visual Studio Team Services Nuget feed.

We use the Visual Studio Team Services to build the class library and have a build definition with a build step that does a `dotnet restore` on the project. The command fails with the following errors:

```
2016-06-28T13:07:09.0634265Z ##[warning]File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.
2016-06-28T13:07:09.0644179Z Executing the following command-line. (workingFolder = C:\a\1\s)
2016-06-28T13:07:09.0644179Z dotnet restore
2016-06-28T13:07:09.0654186Z Error message highlight pattern: 
2016-06-28T13:07:09.0654186Z Warning message highlight pattern: 
2016-06-28T13:07:11.6393062Z log  : Restoring packages for C:\a\1\s\src\Company.Extensions\project.json...
2016-06-28T13:07:11.7623059Z info :   GET https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model'
2016-06-28T13:07:11.8463064Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/Company.model/index.json
2016-06-28T13:07:12.0162954Z info :   Unauthorized https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model' 254ms
2016-06-28T13:07:12.0702952Z log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model''.
2016-06-28T13:07:12.0712954Z log  : Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
2016-06-28T13:07:12.0712954Z info :   GET https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model'
2016-06-28T13:07:12.0722952Z info :   NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/Company.model/index.json 224ms
2016-06-28T13:07:12.1426754Z info :   Unauthorized https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model' 73ms
2016-06-28T13:07:12.1436737Z log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model''.
2016-06-28T13:07:12.1436737Z log  : Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
2016-06-28T13:07:12.1446974Z info :   GET https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model'
2016-06-28T13:07:12.2162787Z info :   Unauthorized https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model' 72ms
2016-06-28T13:07:12.2172786Z error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model''.
2016-06-28T13:07:12.2172786Z error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
2016-06-28T13:07:12.2364584Z error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Company.Model''.
2016-06-28T13:07:12.2374607Z error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Obviously it fails because FeedName requires that we authenticate to it, which is why we also have this `nuget.config` file alongside our `project.json`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="FeedName" value="https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v2" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <FeedName>
    <add key="Username" value="username" />
    <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="the_actual_clear_text_password" />
  </FeedName>
</configuration>
```

This works if we use the Nuget Installer build step, but with `dotnet restore` it does not.

Please help, this is the missing part we need to continue using Visual Studio Team Services to build our projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to this link for details: [.NET Core](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth#net-core).

> .NET Core doesn't currently support encrypted credentials. To use VSTS
>   NuGet feeds with .NET Core applications, you'll need to specify a
>   Personal Access Token in plain text.

Comment: Thank you! Following your link I discovered that I was missing the `<packageSourceCredentials>` tags in my nuget.config. Putting those in resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use a dotnet core build step to restore, build, test, and run other custom dotnet command.

[image]

Below are all the commands available to use

[image]

Selecting **restore** command will enable you to select nuget package source as shown below.

[image]